# Re-factoring Web API controllers using Interfaces and/or Dependency Injection

Tags: design-patterns, interface, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api

I have a bunch of Web API controllers that generally look like this example:

```
  public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
       private readonly context db = new context();
        public Product GetProductById(int id)
        {
            var product = db.products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            var category = db.category.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            if (category == someCategory)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,new HttpError( "Custom Message"));
            }
            if (itsrainingToday == SomeOtherSpaghettiCode)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new HttpError("Some other mess"));
            }
           //and so on and so forth
            return product;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, this is a big ugly mess, esp. if you have hundreds of rules and dozens of controllers. 
What is an efficient approach to factor out these "business rules" so that they can be applied to multiple controllers with overrides?
  I am looking for a good design pattern and an example based on this generic code.

I am aware of Unit of Work, Unity, and other methodologies.  Just need some guidance as to which path to follow.

Comment: if you have "business rules" maybe you should be using a "business object"? will all of your controllers use the same data and the same rules?

Comment: Different controllers will use different sets of rules and with different params.  But many controllers will use the same rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Specification pattern.  You could place one rule in each specification, such as the NotNullProductRule, and chain together the needed specifications in the controller.

Comment: Great pattern!  Looks like it makes a good fit in this situation.  Thanks!